# Vimeo - Fullscreen - Autoplay

Tags: javascript, html, video, video-streaming, vimeo

Can anyone advise whether its possible to get a Vimeo video to Autoplay as a background video - we have a short 5 second video which we would like to autoplay then trigger a script (below) on video complete to load in a overlay with a play button - which then loads in a larger video with a play button - this is what we have so far -

```
<!-- Navigation -->
  <header class=" noPad vidHead" >

 <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/120042881?autoplay=1" style="width:100%; height:auto;"  frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

   <div class="fadeOver">
                 <a href="#"><img src="img/logos and icons/PlayIconVideo.png" width="120" height="136" alt="Play Video"></a>
    </div>

 </header>
```

```
   $(function () {
       var player = $('iframe');
       var url = window.location.protocol + player.attr('src').split('?')[0];
       var status = $('.status');

       // Listen for messages from the player
       if (window.addEventListener) {
           window.addEventListener('message', onMessageReceived, false);
       }
       else {
           window.attachEvent('onmessage', onMessageReceived, false);
       }

       // Handle messages received from the player
       function onMessageReceived(e) {
           var data = JSON.parse(e.data);

           switch (data.event) {
               case 'ready':
                   onReady();
                   break;

               case 'playProgress':
                   onPlayProgress(data.data);
                   break;

               case 'pause':
                   onPause();
                   break;

               case 'finish':
                   onFinish();
                   break;
           }
       }

       // Call the API when a button is pressed
       $('button').on('click', function () {
           post($(this).text().toLowerCase());
       });

       // Helper function for sending a message to the player
       function post(action, value) {
           var data = {
               method: action
           };

           if (value) {
               data.value = value;
           }

           var message = JSON.stringify(data);
           player[0].contentWindow.postMessage(data, url);
       }

       function onReady() {
           status.text('ready');

           post('addEventListener', 'pause');
           post('addEventListener', 'finish');
           post('addEventListener', 'playProgress');
       }

       function onFinish() {
           $(".fadeOver").fadeIn("slow");
       }

       function onPlayProgress(data) {
           status.text(data.seconds + 's played');
       }
   });

 $( ".fadeOver" ).click (function(){

    $( ".vidHead" ).html('<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/119551148" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>');

});

</script>
```

what currently happens is the process works other than the video is tiny and centered rather than full-screen..

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you're asking to toggle fullscreen.

Try this code, which adds the fullscreen request on click of the `fadeOver` button and only updates the src of the iframe, instead of recreating a new one.

```
$(function () {
       var player = $('iframe');
       var url = window.location.protocol + player.attr('src').split('?')[0];
       var status = $('.status');
         $( ".fadeOver" ).hide();
       // Listen for messages from the player
       if (window.addEventListener) {
           window.addEventListener('message', onMessageReceived, false);
       }
       else {
           window.attachEvent('onmessage', onMessageReceived, false);
       }

       // Handle messages received from the player
       function onMessageReceived(e) {
           var data = JSON.parse(e.data);

           switch (data.event) {
               case 'ready':
                   onReady();
                   break;

               case 'playProgress':
                   onPlayProgress(data.data);
                   break;

               case 'pause':
                   onPause();
                   break;

               case 'finish':
                   onFinish();
                   break;
           }
       }

       // Call the API when a button is pressed
       $('button').on('click', function () {
           post($(this).text().toLowerCase());
       });

       // Helper function for sending a message to the player
       function post(action, value) {
           var data = {
               method: action
           };

           if (value) {
               data.value = value;
           }

           var message = JSON.stringify(data);
           player[0].contentWindow.postMessage(data, url);
       }

       function onReady() {
           status.text('ready');

           post('addEventListener', 'pause');
           post('addEventListener', 'finish');
           post('addEventListener', 'playProgress');
       }

       function onFinish() {
           $(".fadeOver").fadeIn("slow");
       }

       function onPlayProgress(data) {
           status.text(data.seconds + 's played');
       }
   });

 $( ".fadeOver" ).click (function(){

    $( "iframe" )[0].src= '//player.vimeo.com/video/119551148';
    requestFullscreen($( "iframe" )[0]);

});

function requestFullscreen(el){
    if (el.requestFullscreen) {
            el.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (el.msRequestFullscreen) {
            el.msRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (el.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            el.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (el.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            el.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }
    }
```